# How can I make this sentence better?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, terminology

The following sentence will go into a technical article and I wanted to know how to write the following sentence in a better form:

> Results are shown when the region localization constraint is enforced and  when it is taken off.

I believe this does not read well. There are two "when"s and they spoil the sentence.

Comment: Change *and* to *as well as*?  "Results are shown when the region localization constraint is enforced as well as when it is taken off."

Comment: "Results are shown when the region localization constraint is (a) enforced or (b) **{removed / discontinued** [CHOOSE ONE]}." Using two "_when_s" doesn't really spoil the sentence, IMHO. It makes it clear. I'd leave them both there. Sometimes deleting too much causes ambiguity and forces awkwardness.

Comment: Results are shown ***with and without [enforcement of]*** the region localization constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Results are shown when the region localization constraint is enforced and when it is taken off.

Without more context the meaning isn't clear; I'd rephrase it in one of the following ways, depending in part on intent.

> Results are displayed first when the region localization constraint is enforced, and again when the constraint is taken off.
>   Results are shown for two cases:  with and without region localization constraints enforced.

Answer (score 3):

Results are shown ***with and without [enforcement of]*** the region localization constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I might rewrite it like this:

> Results are shown when the regional localization constraint is enforced or taken off.

I could probably be able to write a better sentence with more context.